# Symfony 4 + Postgresql: Server still tries to connect to "localhost" database even though I changed the value in doctrine.yaml and .env

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine, virtual-machine

I have recently deployed my symfony app on a virtual machine that will run the app, this virtual machine is connected to my host machine that runs the Postgresql server. I'm trying to change the database url inside the symfony app (I started by changing DATABASE_URL in env to

```
pdo_pgsql://postgres:*password here*@192.168.122.1:5432/postgres?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8
```

However, upon server start and visiting a page, I get the error:

```
      The Web server is using PHP CGI 7.3.21                                                                            
      http://127.0.0.1:8000                                                                                             
                                                                                                                        

[Web Server/PHP ] Aug 18 14:03:53 |ERROR| PHP    Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused 
[Web Server/PHP ] Aug 18 14:03:53 |INFO | PHP       Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting 
[Web Server/PHP ] Aug 18 14:03:53 |INFO | PHP       TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
[Web Server/PHP ] Aug 18 14:03:53 |INFO | PHP    could not connect to server: Connection refused 
[Web Server/PHP ] Aug 18 14:03:53 |INFO | PHP       Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting 
[Web Server/PHP ] Aug 18 14:03:53 |INFO | PHP       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?" at /symfony/dynamic_form_generator/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 73 
[Web Server/PHP ] Aug 18 14:03:53 |INFO | PHP     
[Web Server/PHP ] Aug 18 14:03:53 |ERROR| SERVER POST (500) /login host="127.0.0.1:8004" ip="127.0.0.1" scheme="https"
```

Which clearly shows that Doctrine/PHP dba stuff is trying to connect to localhost:5432 for whatever reason. I have looked up online and the only files mentioned are .env, doctrine.yaml and parameters.yml (which I don't even have in my project structure)

I have cleared the cache twice, but most of the time when I try to clear it I get the error

```
[root@localhost dynamic_form_generator]# php bin/console cache:clear
*
 // Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false                                                        

 ! [NOTE] For better performances, you should move the cache and log directories to a non-shared folder of the VM.      


In Filesystem.php line 176:
                                                                                                                                                                             
  Failed to remove directory "/symfony/dynamic_form_generator/var/cache/prod/doctrine": rmdir(/symfony/dynamic_form_generator/var/cache/prod/doctrine): Directory not empty  
                                                                                                                                                                             

cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

so I have to manually delete the mentioned directory and then retry, which succeeds but upon server run it still shows that the server is trying to run to localhost:5432. What do I do?

these are my parameter files mentioned above:

Doctrine.yaml: (I changed the url to a 'hand-written' value cause I was getting desperate, it does the same thing if i have '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%' instead )

```
doctrine:

    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
        charset: utf8
        url: pdo_pgsql://postgres:* password here *@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8
        user:     "%env(resolve:DB_USERNAME)%"
        password: "%env(resolve:DB_PASSWORD)%"

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '5.7'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
~
```

and .env: (the important part, the rest is comments)

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=prod
APP_SECRET=8cce45f8d9c607e2a1a371349617970c
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16/192.168.122.1
#TRUSTED_HOSTS='^(localhost|example\.com)$'
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# For a PostgreSQL database, use: "postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8"
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=pdo_pgsql://postgres:* password here *@192.168.122.1:5432/postgres?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=192.168.122.1
DB_DATABASE=postgres
DB_PASSWORD= * password here *
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1|192\.168\.122\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###
~
```

- password here * is where the password is supposed to be. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** fixed minor mistake in pasted file content.

Answer (score -1):

After messing about with the configurations for an entire day, I tried running
`php bin/console debug:config doctrine | grep localhost` to see what the problem was if the doctrine was overriding my settings, and indeed there appears to be a hidden parameter "host: localhost".
So all I had to do was go back to the doctrine yaml file, and add the line "host: 192.168.122.1"

so it looks like this:

```
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
        charset: utf8
        url: pdo_pgsql://postgres:* password here *@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8
        user:     "%env(resolve:DB_USERNAME)%"
        password: "%env(resolve:DB_PASSWORD)%"
        host: 192.168.122.1
```

I hope this resolved the issue for anyone who had it!